# Add CSS class to change style of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
@charset "utf-8";

html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.center-container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 /*height: 500px;*/
}

.main-container {
 /*height: 100%;*/
 
}


 
.darktitle {
 color: #000000;
 background: grey;
 font-size: 25px;
}

.titlebar {
 text-align: center; 
 color: #FF0000;
 background: blue;
 font-size: 40px;
}



button {
 padding: 00px;
 font-weight: bold;
 
 font-size:1em;
 font
 
 color: #000000;
 height: 40px;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
 <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
 <body>
  <div class="main-container">
   <h1 id="titlebar" class="titlebar"> Titlebar</h1>
   <div class="center-container" >
     <button id="button1">Button1</button>
     <button id="button2">Button2</button>
     <button id="button3">Button3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   var titlebar = document.querySelector('h1#titlebar');
   var button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
   var button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
   var button3 = document.querySelector('#button3');

   button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    titlebar.innerHTML = 'Button1';

    var result = titlebar.classList.contains('darktitle');
    console.log(result);
    titlebar.classList.add('darktitle');
    var result = titlebar.classList.contains('darktitle');
    console.log(result);

   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hey earthlings,

i started learning HTML and CSS. Currently I'm dealing with style classes. I created a simple example. What I want to reach is, that the titlebar changes the font color, the font-size and the background color if button1 is clicked.

Initially the titlebar has appended the titlebar-class, after button1 is clicked the darktitle-class should also be added and overwrite certain attributes.
However in this configuration it doesn't happen. If you change the order of the .darktitle and .titlebar class in css file it works. I wonder why.

The CSS Styles should be on the same priority level, so I would expect that the laterly assigned would overwrite the attributes.

TNX

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "utf-8";

html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.center-container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 /*height: 500px;*/
}

.main-container {
 /*height: 100%;*/
 
}

.titlebar {
 text-align: center; 
 color: #FF0000;
 background: blue;
 font-size: 40px;
}

.darktitle {
 color: #000000;
 background: grey;
 font-size: 25px;
}


button {
 padding: 00px;
 font-weight: bold;
 
 font-size:1em;
 font
 
 color: #000000;
 height: 40px;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
 <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
 <body>
  <div class="main-container">
   <h1 id="titlebar" class="titlebar"> Titlebar</h1>
   <div class="center-container" >
     <button id="button1">Button1</button>
     <button id="button2">Button2</button>
     <button id="button3">Button3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   var titlebar = document.querySelector('h1#titlebar');
   var button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
   var button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
   var button3 = document.querySelector('#button3');

   button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    titlebar.innerHTML = 'Button1';

    var result = titlebar.classList.contains('darktitle');
    console.log(result);
    titlebar.classList.add('darktitle');
    var result = titlebar.classList.contains('darktitle');
    console.log(result);

   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The order of your css selectors matter when both selectors are being applied to the same element.  Move the ".darktitle" below the ".titlebar" as in this example. Then when applied by the button the ".darktitle" sstyles will override those same properties in ".titlebar".

Please take a look at this link about CSS specificity, there you will read about your question and why not to use !important declaration.

[Specificity at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

you can use !important to override styles like this

```
.darktitle {
    color: #000000!important;
    background: grey!important;
    font-size: 25px!important;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `!important`. It is a nuclear option and almost never has a valid use case.